# How to create product name dynamically?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, name

My product names are created by different values, that are stored in several custom modules. In my list.phtml I create the dynamic product names, that's no problem. But as I want, that the product names are available on all pages (search, list, checkout), I am looking for a possibility to create the product names already within the product collection. What I mean is, when the function getName() is called, the dynamic product name is given as result.

Thx, Christian

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic names of product, You can create `plugin` which will alter/modify original product name dynamically.

create a simple module say `Pawan_SamplePlugin`

> app/code/Pawan/SamplePlugin/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pawan_SamplePlugin',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Pawan/SamplePlugin/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Pawan_SamplePlugin" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    </config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/SamplePlugin/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
      <plugin name="DynamicSetName" type="Pawan\SamplePlugin\Plugin\ProductName" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/SamplePlugin/Plugin/ProductName.php

```
<?php

namespace Pawan\SamplePlugin\Plugin;

class ProductName
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return '|@@' . $result . '|##';
    }
}
```

You can Update `afterGetName` as per your requirement and update product name accordingly.

Hope above will help!

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try it and will give you a feedback

Comment: welcome :) @Dr.ChristianKusche, plz let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Great, it works! Is there a possibility tochoose the plugin depending on which siteis current. What I mean:

Comment: You can add Store dependency and can check current store/website and run above code accordingly.If above solution help/works for you, you can accept and upvote it :)

Comment: Thanks, its working :-)

Comment: Do you know, how I can show HTML tags in my product names. I tried, but the tags are not parsing

Comment: Does the afterGet function work also for attributes? I have an attribute "data_add". Can I change the value with a function like afterGetDataAdd() ???